# query optimization and improve performance

Tags: mysql, django-models, orm

`Child.objects.select_related("parent").filter(parent=parent_instance)` or `Child.objects.filter(parent=parent_instance).select_related("parent")`

which one is less time consuming

I am not sure which one is taking minimum queries and improve performance

Comment: Both will result in the same query.

Comment: Please provide the generated SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both will result in the same query. It is *not* necessary to [**`.select_related(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) or [**`.prefetch_related(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) to filter. If you filter on a related item, it will just make JOINs.

The idea of `.select_related(…)` is only to add the related models in the `SELECT` clause and to prevent making a query when obtaining the `.parent` attribute of any of the `Child`s that arise from the queryset.

Depending on the use-case, you thus might not need to select the parent in the clause, for example if you only will render fields of the `Child` objects, in that case, the most efficient is thus:

```
Child.objects.filter(parent=parent_instance)
```

or:

```
parent_instance.child_set.all()
```